# Java: Make Json output showing "null" explicitly instead of hiding the null field

Tags: java, json

I have the following class, and I do output the objects of the class in Json string format:

```
public final class MyClass {

    private String field1 = null;
    private String field2 = null;

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return toJsonString();
    }

    public final String toJsonString() {
        return (new Gson()).toJson(this);
    }

    :
    :

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        a.field1 = "Hello";

        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

The above code, the main program output is below:

```
{"field1":"Hello"}
```

Is it possible to make it output:

```
{"field1":"Hello", "field2":null}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration for Gson ignores nulls, but you can use GsonBuilder to change that:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
return gson.toString(this);
```

The [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support) describes this, and [the javadocs](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) describe the other options GsonBuilder gives you.